# Can't get the vue router to work properly

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have struggling to get the vue router to work properly, despite the fact that I have tried multiples different ways and read through the documentation, there seems to be something that I don't understand

I know app component is a bit messy, with router view covering router link and there is the component. its because I have tried it all, included the router-view first then it showed everything from my firstUser component, then tried the link, it worked, but it did not go to that page seperately,

I need to make it so that when clicked it should show the firstUser page only, Please help, much appreciated

```js
//This is my app component


<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <router-view> 
      <router-link to="firstUser"> <first-user/> Register </router-link> 
    </router-view>
    <div>
      <h2>Returning user</h2>
      <returning-user />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Registered User</h2>
      <registered-user />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firstUser from "@/components/firstUser.vue";
import returningUser from "@/components/returningUser.vue";
import registeredUser from "@/components/registeredUser.vue";

export default {
  components: { returningUser, registeredUser, firstUser },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
</style>

//this is my fisrtUser component


<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="registerUser">
      <h4 class="">Register</h4>
      <my-input
        v-model="this.firstName"
        type="text"
        class="input"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      <my-input
        v-model="this.lastName"
        type="text"
        class="input"
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
      <myButton @click="registerUser"> Create </myButton>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myInput from "./UI/myInput.vue";
import myButton from "./UI/myButton.vue";
export default {
  name: "firstUser",
  components: { myInput, myButton },
  data() {
    return {
      user: [
        {
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
        },
      ],
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    registerUser() {
      const newUser = {
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
      };
      this.users.push(newUser);
      console.log(newUser);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>


///then this is the index.js from router



import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import firstUser from '@/views/firstUser';


const routes = [{
        path: '/firstUser',
        name: 'firstUser',
        component: firstUser
    }

]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router
```

and

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what the `firstUser`s are. I will assume what you did is intentional and there are two `firstUser`s (one view and one component).

Specify the `to` prop of the `router-link` component as you would the `href` attribute of a link/anchor `<a>` element. That is, the route needs to begin with a slash.

```
<router-link to="/firstUser">
```

Alternatively, you might want to reduce the coupling by declaring the link by route name instead. This way, you can change the route to whatever you want without having to update your link. This can be done by using `v-bind` to tell Vue to parse the prop contents, and by using [different syntax](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html).

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'firstUser' }">
```

See the [Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/).

Comment: Yes, I have two of the same components, one in views, one in components, (can't still understand what should I put where, (sorry I am beginner, and learning on my own).. Then, yes, the router-link was wrong, turns out it worked, but now the home link shows everything but the firstUser component/page and also by manually typing the firstUser will also not yielf in anything

Comment: But including router-view shows the document, but in wierdly wholly way, like everything, then everything again with link

Comment: @Eternal You can checkout vue basic project with User Registration, Login, Vue-Router4, Auth Guard, User Authentication Route, Vuex4, Todo Tutorial and form validations https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue3-todo